# SQL define table column vs row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Is there any performance hit to define more row than column or vice versa?

consider following situation:
I have a store, some foods, price and date

define a table: `method 1`

```
 PriceDate       nchar(10)

   FoodID          int

   FoodPrice       int
```

define a table: `method 2`

```
 PriceDate nchar(10) , Food_1_Price  int, Food_2_Price  int... Food_N_Price  int
```

Comment: Approach #2 clearly **violates** even the **first normal form** of relational database design and it's **not** recommended

Answer (score 3):

Method 1 is the traditional way of storing data in databases.  It has many advantages.  Notably flexibility and ability to query.

Method 2 is discouraged for a variety of reasons:

- The number of "price" columns is fixed, so changing them requires changing the structure of the tables.
- Counting the number of different prices is painful.
- Removing a price is painful.
- Adding a new price is painful.

In addition, each row occupies the (typically) 4-bytes reserved for an integer, even if there is no value.

If you happen to have all values populated, though (or most of them), then the second method actually occupies less space than the first.  This is more dramatic when the columns are variable length strings, because typically no space is used for `NULL` strings.

Under some circumstances, that can make Method 2 desirable.

It is really important to note that there are alternative methods of storing lists in SQL Server -- JSON and XML.  Under some circumstances, these can be a good way to store variable length content.  SQL Server doesn't support arrays, but in databases that do, that is another reasonable alternative.

All that said, though, Method 1 is pretty much the default method and you'd want to demonstrate improvement if you choose an alternative representation.

Answer (score 2):

SQL databases work in sets of data and as such you should *never* include details on the same level within additional columns (Your `method 2`).  Doing this limits your design to as many columns as you create and makes your queries unnecessarily complex.

Your `Method 1` is much more scalable in that you can add new `Food` types without having to change either your schema or your data analysis queries.